# Map variables do not appear in field editor or in project settings

Tags: qgis, expression, spatio-temporal-data

I am attempting to utilize a few of the map variables (particularly the new **@map_start_time** variable associated with the added temporal features in 3.14). I am on version 3.14.1.

I do not see any of the defined "map" variables (seen [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#variables-functions)) either in the project properties "variables" tab nor in the field calculator.

[image: Field calculator showing no map variables available in the "variables" tab]

[image: Project properties showing missing map variables]

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Comment: It's context dependent. You haven't same variables for QGIS main canvas, for a layout or for a layer properties. Activate temporal settings for a layer and go in this layer properties (for example symbology) and find a data defined dropdown combo (at the right of fields) and go in `edit ...`, you'll see the **@map_start_time**.

Comment: OK that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: Is there any way to call this variable globally? I.e. set a label or decoration equal to the current time frame?

Comment: @J.Monticolo please post your comment as an answer so this thread can be marked as answered

Answer (score 1):

Like in [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=map_start_time#variables) :

> 14.3.25. Variables
>
> This group contains dynamic variables related to the application, the project file > and other settings. **The availability of variables depends on the context**

So to have access to the `@map_start_time` variable, activate temporal settings for a layer and go in this layer properties (for example symbology tab) and find a data defined dropdown combo (at the right of fields) and go in `edit ...`.